# Add an element after a specific row in table

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML with `ROW` and `ENTRY`, But I need to add a `ENTRY` only after the first ROW.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<TABLE FRAME="ALL">
<TGROUP COLS="3">
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col1" COLWIDTH="5cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col2" COLWIDTH="6.00cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col3" COLWIDTH="5.91cm"/>
<THEAD>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TA</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TB</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TC</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" MOREROWS="13" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>C</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A1</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B1</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A2</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B2</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>

<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A4</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A5</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A5<PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A6</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A6</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A7</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</TBODY>
</TGROUP>
</TABLE>
```

**XSLT version 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="TABLE/*/ROW">
    <ENTRY>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </ENTRY>
  </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<TABLE FRAME="ALL">
<TGROUP COLS="3">
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col1" COLWIDTH="5cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col2" COLWIDTH="6.00cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col3" COLWIDTH="5.91cm"/>
<THEAD>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TA</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TB</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>TC</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" MOREROWS="13" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>C</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A1</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B1</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A2</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B2</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A4</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A5</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A5<PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A6</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY/>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A6</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A7</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</TBODY>
</TGROUP>
</TABLE>
```

The element `ENTRY` should only be added after the first ROW.

[image: Sample figure]

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please make sure you accept an answer, if it solves your problem. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your temaplate `<xsl:template match="TABLE/*/ROW">` with:

```
<xsl:template match="TBODY/ROW[position() > 1]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:element name="ENTRY"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Matches all `TBODY/ROW` with position greater than 1; Create the element `ROW` and copy his possible attributes. Create the Element `ENTRY` and go ahead with all childs of context-node.

Comment: Thanks @uL1. But, is there a way to add an "if" condition to repeat the same process after MOREROWS is encountered? Thanks :)

Comment: @ShravanVishwanathan you can change the template to `<xsl:template match="TBODY/ROW[preceding-sibling::ROW/ENTRY[@MOREROWS]]">`. will this do the work for you? otherwise i need more information, what is your outcome and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I'm trying to publish a table but the rendering is not good(data is published in wrong column). My XSL is buggy. The MOREROWS actually is used to span the cells. I removed MOREROWS from XML by XSL since the rendering is good that way. But now, the XSL gets confused to check which is the start of the next data in the first column. I have attached a sample figure for clarity.

Comment: The anomaly described is regressive.

Comment: Is it [CALS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CALS_Table_Model) table model? i think there are some transformation for that on SO.

Comment: Yes, its a CALS table model. I'm really struggling with this.. :(

Comment: I'm not sure if we can add a IF condition to check in case if MOREROWS is present then we can follow this procedure.

Comment: For '<xsl:template match="TBODY/ROW[preceding-sibling::ROW/ENTRY[@MOREROWS]]">' how to implement position()>1?